# segue destinationViewController not detecting destiation viewController

Tags: uiwebview, segue

## ViewController.m

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  WebViewDemo
//
//  Created by Vu Van Tiep on 1/15/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Vu Van Tiep. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "WebViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"GoogleSegue"]){
        WebViewController *desView = (WebViewController*) [segue destinationViewController];
        UIWebView *webView = desView.webView;
        if([webView respondsToSelector:@selector(loadRequest:)] || webView != nil){
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        //webView is nil

    }
}

@end
```

## WebViewController.m

```
//
//  WebViewController.m
//  WebViewDemo
//
//  Created by Vu Van Tiep on 1/15/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Vu Van Tiep. All rights reserved.
//

#import "WebViewController.h"

@interface WebViewController ()

@end

@implementation WebViewController
@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
}

@end
```

## WebViewController.h

```
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

when i'm using [segue destinationViewController] i got WebViewControlller object, but when i'm access webView property of that object, it's nil

Can someone plz explain to me? :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view of your WebViewController is not initialized yet. You need to tell it to initialize. Do it after the line

```
WebViewController *desView = (WebViewController*) [segue destinationViewController]; }
```

by adding the line

```
[desView view];
```

This is the same problem as in [Use destinationViewController button in a custom segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311630/use-destinationviewcontroller-button-in-a-custom-segue) . Although this must be a very common problem, I found it hard to locate information about this.